# Convert routes path to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This might be pretty easy to accomplish, but can't find any place that has the answer for this (everything I see with routes happens in the view).

I'm using a 3rd party gem that requires a callback to the controller to build output.

In my call back, I'm passing back a string with a full path.  However, how can I get the path of a route to convert it to a string?

Route example:

```
get 'edit-it/:id', to: 'controller#action', as: :edit_it
```

Controller callback:

```
def button_output
   # TODO: How to pass route to string with the id I need of the current
   # object in callback.

   id = 84848484

   # I've tried (and none seem to work)
   # send(:edit_it_path)
   # :edit_it
   # :edit_it_path(id)
   # :edit_it(id)
   # edit_it_route = edit_it(id) # And combo of all those above

   "<a href=\"#{route_path_goes_here_with_id}\">Edit</a>".html_safe
end
```

This is vastly simplified version, but generally what I can't seem to find.

Am I missing something?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Update your route configuration to accept `id` parameter:

```
get 'edit-it/:id', to: 'controller#action', as: :edit_it
```

You could also add constraint on how `id` should be in your route; e.g. to allow only numbers:

```
get 'edit-it/:id', to: 'controller#action', as: :edit_it, constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
```

Then use it as:

```
"<a href=\"#{edit_it_path(id)}\">Edit</a>".html_safe
```

or (in a view file),

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_it_path(id) -%>
```

and in your controller:

```
link_to('Edit', edit_it_path(id))
```

Comment: Ops, I'll update my question, but I forgot the :id in the route which is already there... just forgot it.

Comment: When I try the method above (in the controller), I get the following message: undefined method `edit_it_path'

Comment: Okay I got it to work, but for some reason I had to include Rails.applicatrion.routes.url_helpers to the controller?!?! I thought this was already defined in ActiveRecord::Base?